# v-text-field text-center not working Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using `v-text-field` and it is not able to set `text-align` to `center`.

I tried these solutions but not working.

1.

```
<v-text-field type="number" class="mr-2 text-center"></v-text-field>
```

2. 

```
<v-text-field type="number" class="mr-2 centered-input"></v-text-field>

.centered-input >>> input {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: View]

[image: Inspect Element]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not work if you give style in the current Vue file. You should add the style as global.

```
.centered-input input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Or it seems like that you've added `scoped` to `<style>` tag. You can remove it to make the style as global.

From

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
```

To

```
<style lang="scss">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
<v-text-field type="number" class="my-field" />

.my-field {
    width: 200px;
}

.my-field input {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
```